# How do I restore a plist on another Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, defaults

I would like to transfer a configuration from one Mac to another using the `defaults` command within BASH.

On one Mac, I can save the configuration by doing:

```
defaults read edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk > bibdesk.plist
```

On the other Mac, I would like to use the `defaults` command to write what I saved, but nothing I can think of makes this work. I've tried the following:

```
defaults write edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk "'$(cat bibdesk.plist)'"
defaults write edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk "\'$(cat bibdesk.plist)\'"
defaults write edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk \'$(cat bibdesk.plist)\'
```

What command will put the configuration back on the other Mac?

Comment: Does `find ~ -name 'edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk*' -print` print a path?

Comment: Yes, it prints several paths. I suspect you are looking for the path I already know: `~/Library/Preferences/edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk.plist`.

Comment: You can just copy the plist to the new computer, without ever using `defaults` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I serendipitously found an answer to my own question. Maybe this will help someone else some day.

Someone suggested trying to read from `stdin`, which doesn't work, **but the error message revealed an undocumented sub-command**:

```
import <domain> <path to plist>      writes the plist at path to domain
import <domain> -                    writes a plist from stdin to domain
export <domain> <path to plist>      saves domain as a binary plist to path
export <domain> -                    writes domain as an xml plist to stdout
```

So, on one Mac I typed:

```
defaults export edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk bibdesk.plist
```

On the other Mac I typed:

```
defaults import edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk bibdesk.plist
```

Done!

Why did Apple have to make this so difficult?!

Comment: They didn't! You could just copy the plist file from one computer to the other. Still -- nice find that the error text gives more commands than the man pages, and these may have some other uses.

Comment: I thought I had read that in some cases the plist file permissions don’t allow writing the file without the command, sometimes also requiring `sudo`.

Comment: Not the ones inside the user Library. The ones in /Library, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

All the `defaults` command does is pull information from various plist files already stored in specific areas of your local filesystem. When @nohillside asked you to use the `find` command, the results you got back should have been the plist file you could directly copy from one mac to the other.

One additional tip:  You can access the contents of a plist file by running `plutil -p`  followed by the plist file.  In this case:
`plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk.plist`

It will be in human readable form, but it's a fast way to check to see if that's the file you're after (assuming you know what the contents generally look like).